# Big O time complexity of a while loop with a random Object

Tags: java, math, random, big-o

```
public class Question2 {
          //running time of function is N!!!!!!
    public static boolean isThere(int[] array, int num, int index){
        boolean isItThere = false;   //running time of 1
        for(int i =0; i <= index; i++){      //running time i
            if(array[i] == num){   //running time of 1
                isItThere = true;   //running time of 1
            }
        }
        return isItThere;
    }


    public static int[] firstAlgo(int N){
            Random random = new Random();  //running time of 1(initilizing)k
          int[] arr = new int[N];
          for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
              int temp = random.nextInt(N+1);  //running time of random is O(1)
              while (isThere(arr, temp, i)){
                  temp = random.nextInt(N+1);
              }
              arr[i] = temp;
          }
         return arr;
    }

}
```

I want to figure out the time complexity of the while loop, I know the running time of the isThere function is N and So is the main for loop in firstAlgo

Comment: It's possible for this program to never terminate - imagine the case where `random.nextInt` always generates the same number for which `isThere` returns true.

Comment: The `while` loop will slow down as `i` increases, so consider this for higher values of `i`. What is the probability of `isThere()` returning `false`? Or rather, for a given value of `i`, **statistically** calculate how many times you have to pick a number from a bag of random numbers to get a number that hasn't already been picked. E.g. if `i == ⅔N`, there is `⅓ = 33%` chance of getting a good number on first pick, but statistically, how many times will you have to pick to get a good number? That statistic formula will help you figure out the Big-O of this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short version:

- The expected runtime is **Θ(N<sup>2</sup> log N)**.
- I have the math to back this up, as well as empirical data.

Here's a plot comparing the empirical amount of work done to the best-fit approximation I got for a function of the form N<sup>2</sup> log N, which was (N<sup>2</sup> ln N) / 1.06:

[image: Comparison of the empirical work done to a predicted N^2 log N behavior, showing an almost exact match.]

Curious? Keep reading. :-)

Let's take a step back from the code here and see what the actual logic is doing. The code works as follows: for each prefix of the array 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., N, the code continuously generates random numbers between 0 and N until it generates one that hasn't been seen before. It then writes down that number in the current array slot and moves on to the next one.

A few observations that we'll need in this analysis. Imagine that we're about to enter the kth iteration of the loop in `firstAlgo`. What can we say about the elements of the first k slots of the array? Well, we know the following:

1. The elements at positions 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., k-1 are all different from one another. The reason for this is that each loop iteration only stops once it's found something that doesn't otherwise appear in the array up to that point.
2. None of those values are equal to 0, because the array is initially populated with 0s and if 0 is generated in a previous step it won't be allowed.
3. As a consequence of (1) and (2), the elements in slots 0, 1, 2, ..., k-1, and k are all different.

Now, we can get down to some math. Let's look at iteration k of the loop in `firstAlgo`. Each time we generate a random number, we look at (k+1) array slots to make sure the number doesn't appear there. (I'm going to use this quantity, by the way, as a proxy for the total work done, since most of the energy will be spent scanning that array.) So then we need to ask - on expectation, how many numbers are we going to generate before we find a unique one?

Fact (3) from the above list is helpful here. It says that on iteration k, the first k+1 slots in the array are different from one another, and we need to generate a number different from all of those. There are N+1 options of random numbers we can pick, so there are (N+1) - (k+1) = N - k options for numbers we could pick that won't have been used. This means that the probability that we pick a number that hasn't yet come up is (N - k) / (N + 1).

A quick check to make sure this formula is right: when k = 0, we are okay generating any random number other than 0. There are N+1 choices, so the probability we do this is N / (N+1). That matches our formula from above. When k = N-1, then all previous array elements are different and there's only one number we can pick that will work. That means we have a success probability of 1 / (N+1), again matching our formula. Cool!

There's a useful fact from probability theory that if you keep flipping a biased coin that has probability p of coming up heads, the expected number of flips before you flip heads is 1 / p. (More formally, [that's the mean of a geometric random variable with success probability p](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution), and you can prove this using the formal definition of expected values and some Taylor series.) This means that on the kth iteration of that loop, the expected number of random numbers we'll need to generate before we get a unique one is (N + 1) / (N - k).

Overall, this means that the expected amount of work done on iteration k of the loop in `firstAlgo` is given by (N + 1)(k + 1) / (N - k). That's because

- there are, on expectation, (N + 1)/(N - k) numbers generated, and
- each generated number requires (k + 1) array slots to be checked.

We can then get our total amount of work done by summing this up from k = 0 to N - 1. That gives us

```
      0+1          1+1          2+1                 N
(N+1)----- + (N+1)----- + (N+1)----- + ... + (N+1)-----
      N-0          N-1          N-2                 1
```

Now, "all" we have to do is simplify this summation to see what we get back. :-)

Let's begin by factoring out the common (N + 1) term here, giving back

```
       /  1     2     3           N  \
 (N+1)|  --- + --- + --- + ... + --- |
       \  N    N-1   N-2          1  /
```

Ignoring that (N + 1) term, we're left with the task of simplifying the sum

```
 1     2     3           N
--- + --- + --- + ... + ---
 N    N-1   N-2          1
```

Now, how do we evaluate this sum? Here's a helpful fact. The sum

```
 1     1     1           1
--- + --- + --- + ... + ---
 N    N-1   N-2          1
```

gives back the [Nth harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) (denoted **H<sub>N</sub>**) and is Θ(log N). More than just being Θ(log N), it's very, very close to ln N.

With that in mind, we can do this rewrite:

```
      1     2     3           N
     --- + --- + --- + ... + ---
      N    N-1   N-2          1

      1     1     1           1
=    --- + --- + --- + ... + ---
      N    N-1   N-2          1

            1     1           1    
+          --- + --- + ... + ---
           N-1   N-2          1

                  1           1    
+                --- + ... + ---
                 N-2          1

+                      ...


                              1    
+                            ---
                              1
```

The basic idea here is to treat (k + 1) / N as (k + 1) copies of the fraction 1 / N, and then to regroup them into separate rows like this.

Once we've done this, notice that the top row is the Nth harmonic number H<sub>n</sub>, and the item below that is the (N - 1)st harmonic number H<sub>n-1</sub>, and the item below that is the (N - 2)nd harmonic number H<sub>n - 2</sub>, etc. So this means that our fraction sum works out to

> H<sub>1</sub> + H<sub>2</sub> + H<sub>3</sub> + ... + H<sub>N</sub>
>
> = Θ(log 1 + log 2 + log 3 + ... + log N)
>
> = Θ(log N!)  (properties of logs)
>
> = **Θ(N log N)**   ([Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)).

Multiplying this in by the original factor of N that we pulled out earlier, we get that the overall runtime is **Θ(N<sup>2</sup> log N)**.

So, does that hold up in practice? To find out, I ran the code over a range of inputs and counted the average number of iterations of the loop in `isThere`. I then divided each term by log N and did a polynomial-fit regression to see how closely the remainder matched Θ(N<sup>2</sup>). The regression found that the best polynomial plot had a polynomial term of N<sup>2.01</sup>, strongly supporting that (after multiplying back in the log N term) we're looking at N<sup>2</sup> log N. (Note that running the same regression but without first dividing out the log N term shows a fit of N<sup>2.15</sup>, which clearly indicates something other than N<sup>2</sup> is going on here.)

Using the the equation Predicted(N) = (N<sup>2</sup> ln N) / 1.06, with that last constant determined empirically, we get the plot up above, which is almost a perfect match.

---

Now, a quick coda to this problem. In retrospect, I should have predicted that the runtime would be Θ(N<sup>2</sup> log N) almost immediately. The reason why is that this problem is closely connected to the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem), a classic probability puzzle. In that puzzle, there are N different coupons to collect, and you keep collecting coupons at random. The question is then - on expectation, how many coupons do you need to collect before you'll have one copy of each of them?

That closely matches the problem we have here, where at each step we're picking from a bag of N+1 options and trying to eventually pick all of them. That would imply we need Θ(N log N) random draws across all iterations. However, the cost of each draw depends on which loop iteration we're in, with later draws costing more than earlier ones. Based on the assumption that most of the draws would be in the back half, I should have been able to guess that we'd do an average of Θ(N) work per draw, then multiplied that to get Θ(N<sup>2</sup> log N). But instead, I just rederived things from scratch. Oops.

Phew, that was a trip! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it empirically.  Just run the code, and time it, with different values of N. I did so, and the complexity seems to be O(N^2).  I ran a bunch of tests, doubling N each time, and the times never seemed to back off from roughly quadrupling.  I got tired of waiting at N = 256000, which took about 200K millis.

If you wanted to go this way, you'd want to do a more careful analysis with more runs.  You could set up an outer loop to keep doing batches of tests, say 10 at each level, timing them, and then doubling N and doing it all again...recording all the times.  You could run the test overnight and get a pretty clear idea of the behavior empirically.

If this isn't the way you want to go about this, it could at least be a way to double-check your answer.

Comment: I have some math and some data that supports a different answer (Theta(N^2 log N) on average). See my answer for details.

Comment: @templatetypedef, I LOVE your answer!  It's definitely better.  The proof way always is, right?  I hope it was clear in mine that I was suggesting a method more than THE answer.  That's why I said "you'd want to do a more careful analysis with more runs".  I did this on the way out the door basically.  If I'd asked the question, and I believed your answer, I'd switch the check mark to your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Big-O is worst case behavior. As mentioned in one of the comments, this has a chance to never terminate leading to Big-O of infinite because this code is non-deterministic.

For an average case where random does what's expected. You are looking at O(N) for the isThere function. For that last iteration to find a value, you will average N operations. At this point you are up to O(N^2). Finally you need to repeat this operation N times to fill the array, which brings you to O(N^3).

Comment: That does give an upper bound, but it's not a very tight bound and will overestimate the average case pretty significantly.

Comment: I don't believe this.  I tested the code empirically, and what I saw was nowhere near O(N^3).  I stated that I wasn't rigorous enough to rule out something like O(N^2.15), but 3?...no way.